# Variable Scope for Cursors in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, cursor

When I run the following SIMPLE code, I get the following error: "Must declare the table variable "@tableName"."

I am not sure why: I tried DECLAREing the variable inside the WHILE statement, but I still get the same silly error. 
All I need this to do is to query all tables in my database (myDB) and output it.

```
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(80)
DECLARE TableName_Cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM myDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables 

OPEN TableName_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM TableName_Cursor INTO @tableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
BEGIN
--DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(80)
--USE myDB
    SELECT * FROM @tableName
    FETCH NEXT FROM TableName_Cursor INTO @tableName
END
CLOSE TableName_Cursor
DEALLOCATE TableName_Cursor
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: As you can see, I even tried using "USE" to ensure it's not a DB use issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing to do with `variable` scope here

You need `Dynamic SQL` to do this

```
Declare @sql varchar(8000)= ''
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
BEGIN
    Set @sql = ''     
    Set @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' +QUOTENAME(@tableName)
    EXEC(@sql)
    FETCH NEXT FROM TableName_Cursor INTO @tableName
END
```

Comment: @LearnByReading - More info on `EXEC` can be found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx

Comment: you were correct, that was the issue. I'm surprised about it though - I've been writing quite a lot of SQL but had not run into this particular issue. Thanks so much!